# SVR sklearn python, error of mix type of Y

Tags: svm, python, scikit-learn

I am new to ML and its concept, I'm trying to implement SVR using sklearn for housing price problem. when I fit the model I received this error

```
'type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError("Mix type of y not allowed, got types set(['continuous', 'multiclass'])",), <traceback object at 0x000000001493E388>v'
```

This my simple try:

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import traceback
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

try:
  dataset=('1000_home.csv')
  data=pd.read_csv(dataset,header=0)
  print(data.shape)
  print(data.head())
  feature_col=['bedrooms','bathrooms','sqft_living','sqft_lot','floors']
  x=data.drop('price',axis=1)
  y=data.price
  x=np.array(x)# trying this to avoid the erro
  y=np.array(y)
  print(x.shape)
  print(y.shape)
  x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=
   cross_validation.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
  print(x_train.shape, "  ",x_test.shape)
  print(y_train.shape,'   ', y_test.shape)
  print(type(y))
  lm=svm.SVR(kernel='linear')
  lm.fit(x_train,y_train)
  y_pred=lm.predict(x_test)

  print(metrics.classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
  print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
  # plt.show()
  #print(lm.intercept_)
  # print(zip(feature_col,lm.coef_))
  #plt.scatter(data.sqft_living,data.price)
  # plt.show()
except:
   print("error")
   e=sys.exc_info()
   print(e)
```

and this a sample of my data where the price is the target (y):

```
price   bedrooms    bathrooms   sqft_living sqft_lot    floors
221900  3   1   1180    5650    1
538000  3   2.25    2570    7242    2
180000  2   1   770 10000   1
604000  4   3   1960    5000    1
510000  3   2   1680    8080    1
1225000 4   4.5 5420    101930  1
257500  3   2.25    1715    6819    2
291850  3   1.5 1060    9711    1
229500  3   1   1780    7470    1
323000  3   2.5 1890    6560    2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are receiving this error is because you are using a type of metrics that is meant for classification, not regression.

sklearn has a great page that shows the different types of metrics that can be used for classification, clustering and regression. You will find that classification_report is for classification. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

For support vector machines that are svr (regression) instead of SVC (classification) you need to use something like r-squared (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score), mean squared error (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error) or explained variance (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score.html#sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it thinks your `y` (`price`) has both multiclass and continuous type variables.  From the sample you gave it looks continuous.  I would verify that your file is not malformed and has only continuous values for the price column